# Firebase RTDB `ref.once()` being executed multiple times

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Playing with firebase RTDB lately, I've been using `.once('value', v => ...)` to build the GUI of my app. The exact code below:

```
<script>
  function onAuthCompleted(usr) {
    var salesTxRef = firebaseApp.database().ref('/salesTx').limitToLast(5);
    salesTxRef.once("value", salesTx => {
      salesTx.forEach(txRef => {
        const tx = txRef.val();
        const $item = $('<li></li>').html('<a href="' + txRef.key + '">$' + tx.total + ' <small>' + tx.currencyCode + '</small></a>');
        $('.main ul').append($item);
      });
    });
  }
</script>
```

The problem is that if I leave the page long enough  opened, `.once()` gets called multiple times (once every 2-3 hours). Is this a bug on the javascript library? Known issue? Is there something that I'm incorrectly doing or a misunderstanding on my part?

Comment: What calls `onAuthCompleted()`? Because if that is based on the Firebase Authentication `onAuthStateChanged()` callback, it will be called hourly when the access token refreshes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Frank van Puffelen pointed out in the comment, the problem came from the method that called `onAuthCompleted(usr)`:

```
firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    if (typeof onAuthCompleted == 'function') { 
      onAuthCompleted(user); 
    }
  } else {
    console.log('User is not logged in. Cannot start session.');
  }
}, function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

The `onAuthStateChanged()` being called hourly to refresh the session caused `onAuthCompleted()` to be called again thus registering the `.once()` method one more time (every ~hour). That was causing the strange perceived behavior.

I can confirm that `.once()` works as expected and it was my misunderstanding on how `onAuthStateChange()` works.

Thanks,